# How do I fit label precisely around bottle, specifically the circumference?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, measurement

I plan on wrapping a label around this bottle but the label gets distorted everytime, so I've concluded I need measurements to match. I've thought about making edge loops to get a specific height when making a selection and as for the circumference I can only think of counting all the faces and multiplying length times that. Am I on the right track? Let me know if there's a more effective way of achieving this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unwrap a cylinder in correct proportion:

- Cut a vertical seam where you want it
- Set an orthogonal view (poles or equator.. here, equator)
- In edit mode, <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap  with 'Cylinder Projection' and settings as shown..

[image]

- Oddly, in the 'Radius' field, entering `pi*radius`

.. which  doesn't make sense to me .. but there it is...

Comment: I am very confused about both the question and the answer. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: I interpreted the OP as being about how to generate a UV map for a cylinder in such a way that, if you use it to map a flat image of a label, it winds up on the surface of the cylinder without non-uniform scaling, or distortion.